# Golang go-pg relation recursive query

Tags: go, go-pg

I will need to join with recursive, something like this :

```
SELECT a.*, b.* c.* FROM a
LEFT JOIN b on b.id = a.b_id
LEFT JOIN c ON c.id = b.c_id
```

And my model definition is :

```
type A struct {
    ID int,
    NameA string,
    B_id int
    B *B,
    C *C,
}

type B struct {
    ID int,
    C_id int,
    NameB string,
    C C,
}

type C struct {
    ID int,
    NameC string,
}
```

I try to use the Relation but didn't works :

```
a := A{}
//does not work
db.Model(&a).Relation("B").Relation("C").First()

//works
db.Model(&a).Relation("B").First()
```

How I can achieve the recursive join on go-pg, please let me know if anyone has experience with it. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to indicate that it's actually a relation on the second struct:

```
db.Model(&a).Relation("B").Relation("B.C").First()
```